# Is the database used by django subqueries sticky?

Tags: django-models, celery

I am having a problem with django subqueries. When I fetch the original QuerySet , I specify the database that I need to use. My hunch is that the later subquery ends up using the 'default' database instead of what the parent query used.

My models approximately look like so (I have several):-

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author_address=models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author, null = True)
```

Now I fetch a QuerySet representing all books that are called Mark like so:-

```
b_det = Book.objects.using('some_db').filter(book_name = 'Mark')
```

Then later somewhere in the code I trigger a subquery by doing something like:-

```
if b_det:
    auth_address = b_det[0].author.author_address
```

My problem is that arbitrarily in some cases , on my live server, the subquery fails even though there is valid data for that author's id. My suspicion is that the subquery is not making use of the same database 'some_db'. Is this possible? Is it so that the database that needs to be used is not sticky in subqueries? It is just a hunch that this might be a problem, it is happening in the context of a celery worker, is it possible that the combination of celery with django ORM has some bug?

I have solved this each time this occurred by doing a full fetch by invoking *select_related* like so.

```
b_det = Book.objects.using('some_db').select_related('author').filter(book_name = 'Mark')
```

So right now, the only way for me to solve the problems is determine beforehand all the data that I will need, and make sure that the top level fetch has all those inner model references using *select_related*. Any ideas why something like this would fail?

I am unable to recreate this locally else I would have debugged it. Like I said, it is pretty random.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have an handle on this now. My assumption that the subqueries would remain sticky to the original database is wrong. What django does is that first it hits the database router that is configured. If that does not return anything only in that case it makes use of the original database.

So, if the configured database router returns some database to be used then that gets used. In my opinion this is wrong and we need to use the original database first and then check the database router.